# How to pass `hyphenpenalty` as a CLI parameter to Pandoc?

Tags: latex, command-line-interface, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I want to convert `MD` to `PDF` with `Pandoc` and `pdflatex`:

```bash
pandoc \
  "$md_file" \
  --pdf-engine=pdflatex \
  --variable=geometry:a4paper \
  --variable=fontsize=12pt \
  --output "${md_file%.md}.pdf"
```

---

**How do I [**disable** hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5039/297656) using a CLI paramter?**

---

I've tried to set it within the markdown file, as a [YAML metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block), and it's working:

```markdown
---
header-includes: |
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=10000
---

The rest of the markdown file…
```

---

But… I want the settings for multiple files and I do *not* want to "hardcode" them inside the markdown file, so I've extracted the above [to a dedicated](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata-file) `pdf_config.yml` file, and it is also working:

```yaml
header-includes: |
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
  \exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

```bash
pandoc
  --metadata-file ./pdf_config.yml \
```

---

Finally, I do *not* want an extra YAML file -> I want everything in my bash script -> so, **I want to pass the metadata by a [CLI parameter](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata)**. I'v tried multiple variations of the below, with no success:

```bash
pandoc
  --metadata=header-includes:hyphenpenalty=10000 \
  --metadata=header-includes:exhyphenpenalty=10000 \
```

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.45 h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `header-includes` metadata value, set the variable of the same name instead:

```
pandoc -V header-includes="\\hyphenpenalty=10000 \\exhyphenpenalty=10000" ...
```

This will be inserted into the document verbatim.

Comment: You have a typo in the word "exhyphenpenalty" – but otherwise, it is working, big thanks!

Comment: BTW, why do u use double backslash? single one works as well…

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the typo. The double backslash is just a habit of mine, I use them whenever I have quoted strings in bash just to avoid problems with `"\n"` and the like. They aren't necessary.

Answer (score -2):

You should pass the HY register with the value 0 with the -rHY=0 command line flag.

Then pass the metadata by a CLI parameter.

Comment: What is the `HY register`? The Pandoc docs are telling me that `-r FORMAT` is for specifying the input format. I don't see any "register" options…